# A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if $G$ can be coloured with 2 colours

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, bipartite-graphs

I've been stuck on this question for some time, can anyone please help me out with it...

Definition: A graph $G = (V, E)$ can be coloured with $k$ colours if $\forall v \in V$, $v$ is assigned exactly one of $k$ colours and $\forall e = (u, v) \in E$, $u$ and $v$ are coloured with different colours. Prove that a graph $G = (V, E)$ is bipartite if and only if $G$ can be coloured with 2 colours.

Comment: What definition of "bipartite" are you using?

Comment: choloboy7: When you receive a helpful answer, we encourage you to accept it. (You can accept one answer per question.) To accept an answer, you can simply click on the $\checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. Note, for each answer you accept (one per question), you receive $+2$ reputation points!

Comment: i know i know! I usually do, my apologies for forgetting to accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big HINT: If you have a $2$-coloring, let $V_0$ be the set of vertices of one color, and let $V_1$ be the set of vertices of the other color. Are there any edges between two vertices in $V_0$ or between two vertices of $V_1$? If not, you have a bipartite graph with vertex sets $V_0$ and $V_1$.

On the other hand, if $G$ is bipartite with vertex sets $V_0$ and $V_1$, what happens if you color every vertex in $V_0$ one color and every vertex in $V_1$ another color?

Comment: Surely the hint for the second part was completely unnecessary, at least initially?

Comment: @Tara: Hard to say, considering where it originated.

Comment: My point is that you can ask if the OP can get that part by themselves first before giving a hint.

Comment: @Tara: I understood what you meant.